# Electron store OAuthToken to use in Angular

Tags: angularjs, oauth, electron

I am developing an Angular App that runs with Electron. Inside Electron I am using OAuth based on this Tutorial http://manos.im/blog/electron-oauth-with-github/.

Everything works fine and I receive the access_token inside the main.js from Electron. To call my endpoint I need this token inside my Angular Service. How do I pass this token to Angular?

*My Angular App is Bundled with Wepack and then included in Electron.*

Comment: Would it be possible to write my token inside the main.js to the local storage and then read that token with angular? If yes. How can I write to the local Storage with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the github access token is received in the main process. Let me know if I misunderstood.

It sounds like your question could be rephrased, "How do I share data between the main process and renderer processes?". The easiest way to do this is via [IPC](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) ([inter-process communication](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md)), which allows you to send messages and data between the main and renderer processes.
This might be helpful as well: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/faq/electron-faq.md#how-to-share-data-between-web-pages

```
//from the main process
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

function githubRequestCallback(response) {
  window.webContents.send('github-access-token', { 
    token: response.data.token 
  });
}

//in a renderer
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.on('github-access-token', (event, {token}) => {
  console.log('i haz the token', token);
});
```

If that access token is received in a renderer (that article seems to be assuming that), then yes, you could set in localStorage and I think it would be available in all renderer processes. Note that the `localStorage` API is only available from the renderer process, so if the main process needs to get a hold of it, then you may want to consider something else or just use IPC to pass it around.

Another option would be to persist the token to a file, for example using [electron-config](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-config) (persists it as JSON) or if you have lots of data storage needs, something like LevelDB. The main and renderer processes could then read/write the same config file as needed.

Juggling data around multiple processes is sort of a new challenge for most JS people, I'm still figuring it out myself :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. I have successfully integrated the ipcMain inside the Main Process. No I am trying to integrate the render Code inside my Angular2 Service. Unfortunately ipcRenderer is always undefined. Do you know how I can Recive the message sended from the main process inside my angular 2 service?

Comment: @Trafalgar are you using a module bundler like webpack? Most module bundlers rewrite `require`.

Comment: Yes I am using Webpack. Therefore I am not sure how to correctly include electron.ipcRenderer

Comment: @Trafalgar you might want to look into something like this: https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer Basically webpack rewrites all your requires as a part of its bundling process, but it can't resolve native node and electron modules. The end of this article explains it a bit: https://medium.com/@Agro/developing-desktop-applications-with-electron-and-react-40d117d97564#.xts8ebjx6 The webpack target plugin should solve this issue by ignoring requires to electron modules.